# CodeIgniter Active Record unknown column in where clause

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

This is my Active record query! It keeps giving me error that unknown column in where clause:

```
public function getItemSale($start, $end = 9,$userid,$loc_id,$item)
{
    $sql = "SELECT Name, sum(Qty) as total, sum(Price) as sale  from itransfile where 
    SESSIONID = GETSESSIONID(?) && PayMode IN('CASH','Cheque')" ;

     if(is_numeric($loc_id))
        $sql .= " && location_id = " .$loc_id ;
     else
        $sql .= " && location_id IN(SELECT location_id FROM client_locations where client_id = " .$userid. ")";

     if($item != 'All')
        $sql .= " && Name = `{$item}`"; 

     $sql .= " group by Name  order by sale desc LIMIT ? OFFSET ?;"; 

     $query = $this->db->query($sql, array(date("Y-m-d"),$end,(int)$start));

     return $query->result_array();
}
```

[image]

Comment: what does your table look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `backticks` and use `AND` in place of `&&`

```
 $sql = "SELECT Name, sum(Qty) as total, sum(Price) as sale  from itransfile where 
        SESSIONID = GETSESSIONID(?) AND PayMode IN('CASH','Cheque')";

if (is_numeric($loc_id))
    $sql .= " AND location_id = " . $loc_id;
else
    $sql .= " AND location_id IN(SELECT location_id FROM client_locations where client_id = " . $userid . ")";

if ($item != 'All')
    $sql .= " AND  Name = '{$item}'";

$sql .= " group by Name  order by sale desc LIMIT ? OFFSET ?;";

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array(date("Y-m-d"), $end, (int) $start));

return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Done but still problem not solved, it gives error                                                  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 group by Name order by sale desc' at line 2

SELECT Name, sum(Qty) as total, sum(Price) as sale from itransfile where SESSIONID = GETSESSIONID('2015-05-16') && PayMode IN('CASH','Cheque') && location_id = 1 && Name = COMBO 1 group by Name order by sale desc;

Comment: i think unknown column problem is solved. I think  is is new probple

Comment: @Mateen-ul-haq  I think COMBO 1 should be in single or double quotes like "COMBO 1"

Comment: @saty no if item has no space in it, it still gave the same error

Comment: SELECT Name, sum(Qty) as total, sum(Price) as sale from itransfile where SESSIONID = GETSESSIONID('2015-05-16') AND PayMode IN('CASH','Cheque') AND location_id = 1 && Name = 'COMBO 1'  group by Name order by sale desc  this is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Replace the **backticks** with **single quotes**. In MySql, backticks indicate that an indentifier is a column name:

```
$sql .= " && Name = '{$item}'";
```

Comment: Done but problem not solved, Unknown column 'Abc' in 'where clause'

SELECT Name, sum(Qty) as total, sum(Price) as sale from itransfile where SESSIONID = GETSESSIONID('2015-05-16') && PayMode IN('CASH','Cheque') && location_id IN(SELECT location_id FROM client_locations where client_id = 1) && Name = Abc group by Name order by sale desc;

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line

```
if($item != 'All')
        $sql .= " && Name = `{$item}`";
```

with

```
if($item != 'All')
            $sql .= " && Name = '{$item}'";
```